# Java: Read char and bytes from Text

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I hope there are some nice person who could help me out to read a char and byte from a single line whose datatype is Text.

I have a Text.toString() where the pattern is first 2 char followed by 2 bytes and the remaining char. This is a fixed length file of 70.

I have to ignore the 2 bytes and the 2 bytes appears as special character(sometime appears as single character and sometimes as 2 characters).

I tried using UTF-8, iso-8859-1, CP850, US-ASCII etc. as below

```
byte[] utf8bytes = value.toString().getBytes("iso-8859-1");
LOG.info(new String(utf8bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Input data:

```
12��00a1A10a0000000abcdef0ghijkl0abcde000000f0gh1a0bcded1234z1234  z000000000000002
12ɹ00a1A10a0000000abcdef0ghijkl0abcde000000f0gh1a0bcded1234z1234  z000000000000002
```

Output should be:
    1200a1A10a0000000abcdef0ghijkl0abcde000000f0gh1a0bcded1234z1234  z000000000000002
    1200a1A10a0000000abcdef0ghijkl0abcde000000f0gh1a0bcded1234z1234  z000000000000002

This script is in Hadoop Mapper.
Any help would be great since I have been trying hard to make this work.

Thank you,
Revathy.

Comment: You could use `substring` and remove the element positions you don't need, if they are always in the same place.

Comment: @rbheemana, The 2 byte is Mainframe binary data. Do you have any references to convert/skip this 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you are sure that all the other characters in the `String` are going to be alphanumeric, you can just use `replaceAll` to remove them. Note that I left the space in there as it looks like your expected output wants to keep that.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
```

[See it online!](https://ideone.com/gBRwXa)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I mentioned that the 2 bytes is special characters. It can be any character.

Comment: Hmm. So your input could be `12T00a1A10a000001...` and you want to remove the `T` in this example?

Comment: yes, basically read position 1-2 as chars and read the next 2 bytes and start the remaining as chars.

Comment: @Aavik Probably quite messy but: convert your String to a char array. Remove the first two chars. Convert to byte array. Remove the first two bytes. Convert back to char array (with adding the first two chars from the original one). Messy, huh? I don't have the time to give it a shot to see if it will or not work, so I can't update my answer at the minute.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this one.

Comment: this didn't work.                                                                                      byte[] utf8bytes = value.toString().substring(2).getBytes();
LOG.info("Byte length: "+utf8bytes.length);
byte[] newBytes = Arrays.copyOf(utf8bytes,2);
LOG.info("New Byte length: " + newBytes.length); As each character it is taking 2 bytes when converted from Text to bytes. I tried reading this as sequence file but it errors saying java.io.IOException: $Filename not a SequenceFile

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of box to do this .

1. Write your custom recordReader with the logic you intent.
2. use String substring.
3. Use byteBuffer and extract out the indices you dont need.

Comment: I tried this logic in mapper. Its a TextInptFormat where each line is read as Text and is converted to String, and then converted to bytes. For conversion to bytes I tried various charset. As suggested by you, converting substring to byteBuffer, what charset to use?

Comment: Tried ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(value.toString().substring(2,3)); The indices does not work since I do not know if it is substr(2,3) or substr(2,4) as it is in bytes.

Comment: I read the file as BufferedInputStream, read the first chunk and trying to replace 2-3 position with space(0x20) using ByteBuffer. This doesn't seem to work. Do you have reference?